Problem with a copy_message() method (Pyrogram)
I need to get only the text of the message, but when I get message["text"] and send it to the chat I've chosen, program gives an issue 'Message' object is not subscriptable


client.start()


chat = input("@user: ")

id = client.get_chat_history_count(chat_id = chat)
randid = random.ranint(1, id)

message = client.copy_message(chat_id = chat, from_chat_id = chat, message_id = randid)

tmessage = message["text"]


send = client.send_message(chat_id = chat, text = tmessage)

client.stop()

I tried to make a for cycle with lines
if message["Message"] is None:
    continue

or
if message.Message is None
    continue

No one works

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

copy_message returns a Message object, but not dict - documentation
Change message["text"] to message.text - that's the correct way to get field from object:
tmessage = message.text

